# Minikube not starting on macOS

Tags: macos, minikube

I am not able to start minikube on my mac os

I am getting the below error

```
    minikube start
  minikube v1.29.0 on Darwin 13.2.1 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the virtualbox driver

❌  Exiting due to DRV_UNSUPPORTED_OS: The driver 'virtualbox' is not supported on darwin/arm64
```

Help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope the shared information was helpful to you in overcoming the issue. If you have any further queries, I am happy to offer further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cs101.blog/2023/01/12/run-a-minikube-on-mac-with-m1-chip/) written by Mingmin:

> VirtualBox is not supported, even you download the developer version
> for MacOS/ARM M1/M2, you would see an error like ‘Exiting due to
> DRV_UNSUPPORTED_OS: The driver ‘virtualbox’ is not supported on
> darwin/arm64′.

A list of all the available supported drivers for Apple can be found [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/).

You can also check the doc [Minikube on M1 pro without a docker desktop](https://0to1.nl/post/minikube-m1-pro-issues/) written by Rogier Dikkes.